# ¿Cómo cerrar un messagebox en python?

Tags: python, tkinter

En el sencillo programa en el que ando trabajando, tengo un problema, y es que después de verificar si el número al azar es mayor, menor o igual, me sale la misma ventana y no me permite escribir nuevamente otro número. Ando usando Tkinter.

```
def principal():

Numerosistema=random.randrange(2001)
Numerousuario = int(entradaNumerousuario.get())

while Numerousuario != Numerosistema:
    if Numerousuario > Numerosistema:
        messagebox.showinfo(message="Su numero es mayor al que yo he escogido, siga intentando", title="Alerta")



    elif Numerousuario < Numerosistema:
        messagebox.showinfo(message="Su numero es menor al que yo he escogido, siga intentando", title="Alerta")



    else:
        messagebox.showinfo(message="Adivinaste mi numero, ganaste", title="Alerta")
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¿Puedes incluir un [ejemplo mínimo reproducible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

No es un problema relacionado con Tkinter ni con que no puedas cerrar el messagebox, es un problema del código.

Actualmente lo que está haciendo tu código es: cuando ejecutas el método 'principal()', generas un número aleatorio, luego obtienes el número introducido en lo que supondré que es un 'Entry', y después entras en un bucle donde comparas esos dos valores constantemente, porque como dentro del bucle no das opción a que el valor del 'Entry' pueda cambiar, se sigue comparando, y ese bucle nunca va a acabar.

Lo que deberías hacer para que te funcione es: tener un método que sea el primero en ejecutarse, donde declaras el valor aleatorio, declaras y creas los elementos de Tkinter, además de un Button que al pulsarlo se ejecute un método, que con el cual obtengas el valor del Entry (int(entradaNumerousuario.get())), y hagas las comparaciones que estabas haciendo, llamando al final a el messagebox.

Resumido: tienes que tener un método donde declares las variables, y otro método que compare esos dos valores y muestre el messagebox.

Cuando trabajes con Tkinter tienes que pensar que no es tan lineal como puede ser un programa simple, sino que funciona más por eventos que pueda generar el usuario como por ejemplo darle a un botón.

Además te recomiendo que utilices PEP 8 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), para que facilites la lectura de tu código a cualquier otra persona.